# Why is window.open prepending a default url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Code**

```
<a href="www.someurl.com" id="equipment_url_readonly">www.someurl.com</a>

$(document).on('click','#equipment_url_readonly', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(url); //It console logs correctly the url
    window.open(url,"_blank");
});
```

But whenever I click on the anchor tag, it prepends the url of the parent,
 so for example my current page that has that url is `www.mycurrentpage.com/this-page`. When I click on that link, it opens a new window with a url of:

```
www.mycurrentpage.com/this-page/www.someurl.com
```

Any idea how this happened?

Comment: The lack of `http://` (or simply `//`) causes the browser to assume a `relative` path. Adding `http://` should open the window with the `absolute` path, `http://www.someurl.com`.

Comment: You need more jQuery for that. :p

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. yes, it solved the issue, but I can't assume that the url is always http, what if it is https? or what if the user entered a url that has already 'http' in it? Sorry for asking this follow up question, but the href above is user entered. Thanks

Comment: @BelmarkCaday don't worry you can use `http`, browser automatically convert it to `https` if it is

Comment: Why can't `target="_blank"` serve your purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that your anchor doesn't contain an absolute URL because it misses the protocol (i.e. "http://" or even "//").

This should fix it:

```
<a href="//www.someurl.com" id="equipment_url_readonly">www.someurl.com</a>
```

The above will work for both secure and non-secure pages.

Comment: yes, it solved the issue, but I can't assume that the url is always http, what if it is https? or what if the user entered a url that has already 'http' in it? Sorry for asking this follow up question, but the href above is user entered. Thanks

Comment: @BelmarkCaday Updated the answer; using "//" should work in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish opening a new window without any Javascript.

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com" target=_blank>www.someurl.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below, i think its enough for your purpose. hope it will helps.

**you have to use `http://` or  `//` before your url**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('http://www.someurl.com', '_blank');" >www.someurl.com</a>
```